# Hiding and showing html code if javascript is on/off

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

So I have 2 links that I would like to show if javascript is on and hide when it is off, and when the javascript is off, I would like to show 2 other links in its place with noscript tag.

What I have so far is:

-js here-
show 2 links if js is on and hide when it is disabled
-js here-

-noscript-
link 1
link 2
-noscript-

I only have experience in PHP and am not very familiar with javascript.

What would be the best way to go about this? Should there be a javascript function of some kind to make the show/hide function work? But if javascript is off, how will the function run to hide the links?

If someone can point me in the right direction to go about this or provide me with a simple code snippet, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hide the links using CSS - not visible by default

   ```
   <a id="link1" href="#" style="display: none">Script link 1</a>
   <a id="link2" href="#" style="display: none">Script link 2</a>
   ```
2. Show the links using Javascript - they are only visible if Javascript is on, of course

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('link1').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('link2').style.display="block";
   </script>
   ```

   Depending on what you need, you can use any other `display` property (link is `inline` by default, I added `block` here, use whichever you need).
3. Add the `noscript` stuff - only visible when Javascript is off

   ```
   <noscript>
   -two other links-
   </noscript>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I've often seen this done with a CSS class on the BODY tag.  For example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    BODY A { display: none; }
    BODY.script A { display: inherit; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">Shows with Script</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You can then use the script:

```
document.body.className = 'script';
```

For browsers that support Javascript, the `script` CSS class will be added and `BODY.script` styles will be used.  Otherwise, regulard `BODY` styles will be used.

You can then define exactly how you want any element on the page to display with or without script enabled.  Likewise, you could reverse this and give BODY a `noscript` style, then remove it through script.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgHky/)

Comment: +1 This is a neat technique. Only weakness is that it might destroy other classes set on the body.

Comment: @bažmegakapa - Agreed, if you had a bunch of `BODY` CSS selectors, it might be best to define a `noscript` CSS class which would be *removed* on load.

Comment: this worked great, but attaching it to the body tag causes too many problems for my current code! thank you for the help!

Comment: @usr122212 - Yea if it's just one or two links, then this might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without `noscript`, as follows

**HTML**

```
<a href="" style="display:none" id='javascript_link1'>JS link-1</a>
<a href="" style="display:none" id='javascript_link2'>JS link-2</a>
<a  href="" id='nonjs_link1'>link-1</a>
<a href="" id='nonjs_link2'>link-2</a>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('javascript_link1').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('javascript_link2').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('nonjs_link1').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('nonjs_link2').style.display="none";​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RS8m6/2/).